# how to clean the extra elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

this is my php code.

```
while($fetchRes=mysql_fetch_assoc($query9)) {       
    $rows[] = array(
    array('iso'=>$staff_id,
    'name'=>$name,
    'iso3'=>$last_name,
    'numcode'=>$email
    ),);

    }

echo '<pre>'; 
    $rows=print_r($rows);
    echo '</pre>';
```

after running this code i am getting the following output.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 008 [name] => 
dev [last_name] => abc [email] => abc@gmail.com ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 7002 
[name] => Sheela [lastname] => Mbhhh [email] => 7002@iem.com ) )
```

but problem is that i want the following type of array

```
array(
    array('id'=>'008 ',
    'name'=>'dev ',
    'last_name'=>'abc ',
    'email'=>'abc@gmail.com',
    ),
    array('id'=>'AL',
    'name'=>'Albania',
    'last'=>'ALB',
    'email'=>'8',
    )
```

means i dont want the extra things in my array like Array ( 
[0] =>, Array ( 
[1] =>

Answer (score 0):

Then why do you use an array inside another array? (`$rows[] = array(array(...`)

Try this:

```
while($fetchRes=mysql_fetch_assoc($query9)) {       
    $rows[] = array(
    'iso'     => $staff_id,
    'name'    => $name,
    'iso3'    => $last_name,
    'numcode' => $email
    );

}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the output of print_r only? Try var_dump then.

Comment: actuly i dont want any indexes in my array just want to print plain array without indexes.

Comment: Then iterate over the array and echo the values. Those extra elements are not real elements, it's just output that print_r generates. You array is just as you want it.